# What's the most efficient way to get source code of web page in C?

Tags: c, networking

In **PHP** I can do it as simple as :

```
file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');
```

What's the shortest code to do the same in **C**?

**UPDATE**

When I compile the sample with curl, got errors like this:

```
unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_cleanup referenced in function _main
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/), refer to their [example C snippets](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "curl.haxx.se");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +0.3 for the clear and concise answer, +0.7 for using the swedish top-level domain =)

Comment: @manneorama :-) - Thanks although I should point out that we shouldn't use curl.haxx.se for testing instead maybe use www.sweden.gov.se

Comment: But I got errors like this when compiling it: `unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_cleanup referenced in function _main`

Comment: I don't believe there are libs in the source distribution. You should build it yourself, shouldn't you?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [libcurl C interface](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/)

Answer (score 1):

I should have commented the `Richard Harrison` good answer, but I have not 50 reputations points yet, so I put here as an answer my hint to `ieplugin` for compiling the code:

On Ubuntu 10.04 (and supposing you named the source file `getpage.c`):

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-dev
gcc getpage.c -lcurl -o getpage
```

Comment: how to compile it from source?

Comment: @`ieplugin`: I think it would be better if you ask a new question on `curl` compiling and accept `Richard` answer to this question.