# how to compile curl from source in windows?

Tags: c, windows, curl

I created this question for the suggestion under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180451/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-source-code-of-web-page-in-c/3214989#3214989)

Comment: Why compile it yourself?  The download page has Windows binary packages with all the necessary components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cURL documentation explains in details how to build it on Windows. You should read docs/INSTALL in the source tarball.

There are many way to do this depending you compiler (msvc, mingw, borland) and build system (makefile, IDE)...